# Http Live Streaming on Android 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I would like to play a http live steaming link(.m3u8) on android. Can you please let me know how to write code for that (snippet)?

I tried the following(on Activity's onCreate event) but it wouldnt work (says Cant play video) :

```
VideoView vv = new VideoView(this);
Uri uri =Uri.parse("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8");
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
setContentView(vv);
```

note: using emulator for testing
thanks for the help

Comment: Did you call vv.start() after setting the ContentView?
This should work.
Is there any exception you get?

Comment: hi rajdeep, just added vv.start() but doesnt help - same output. LogCat shows a couple of messages: Error message: "Unable to create media player" . and the exception is java.io.IOException : setDataSource failed.

Comment: AFAIK, the WIFI network layer on Emulator is sort of mocked from underlying operating system network layer, if your computer sit behind some Proxy server, you will probably get similar kind of error (If I recall, I used to get similar kind of error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

```
    String httpLiveUrl = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

---

OR

Try using the [VitaMio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) media player

> HTTP live streaming (M3U8), for Android 2.1+

`edit`: The VitaMio player is dead

---

I think this will work just fine in the actual device, since it works in HoneyComb, the emulator can be broken sometimes

Comment: thanks Reno, But I came to know that android 3+ have default support for http live streaming(HLS). Since I will be developing only for android 4, is VitaMio required ?

Comment: There are [some known issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17118) with it. The emulator is not reliable it seems.

Comment: reno, it doesnt seem to work. What I did was : In the Acitivity's onCreate function I added - VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);<pasted you code>;setContentView(videoView); - When i run this I get following in logCat: 1. D - MediaPlayer - Couldnt open files on client side, trying server side  2. E - MediaPlayer - error(1, -2147483648) and two other line with same error messages as second one. On the emulator the output is "Cant play video" dialog.

Comment: +1 This is the correct way to do it on Emulator, I am using same piece of code in two of my Android projects without any problem. Note, for some real device, httplive doesn't work, need change it back to http.

Comment: the `httplive` scheme is not supported.

Comment: Reno is there any other way to play m3u8 file  with out using Third party library

Comment: Did anyone get this working? I get the same prob as @Jay on Anroid 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might not be fully supported in the emulator.
This runs fine on a ICS device

Comment: You have a ICS device? It is not released yet

Comment: Note: I am part of the android devrel team at Google